# Can we Update , Delete , Insert and Truncate The Records on Materialized View?

Tags: postgresql

when I am trying to delete, update or truncate the record in Materialized view, I cant do that.
can we do DML Operation on materialize view?
please let me know what I am doing wrong and guide me to follow right way.

Comment: No, not possible. The only way to change the content of a mview is `refresh materialized view ...`

Comment: *Technically* it's possible, just not allowed by default (because postgres has no way to know the mapping): you can DELETE FROM a view (materialized or not) if you set up an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger, which converts the DML to the actual operation on the backing data, then refresh the view (if materialized).